# Error: can't read the block: &{NOT_FOUND}

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

After adding an organization to the channel I am unable to get block 0 it says:

```
2021-01-05 10:30:48.412 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2021-01-05 10:30:48.500 UTC [cli.common] readBlock -> INFO 002 Expect block, but got status: &{NOT_FOUND} Error: can't read the block: &{NOT_FOUND}
```

Any idea how to resolve this?
I am using v2.3 for the orderer and peers, and I am able to fetch the block with the other organization's peer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

1. Ran startup.sh, so that recreated the channel allarewelcome (and deleted all the existing peer containers)
2. For both the peer definitions in docker-compose.yml file, i changed image: hyperledger/fabric-peer to image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:1.4.4
   After starting the peer containers, i was able to fetch the genesis block for allarewelcome channel, as also able to join it.

Comment: I've created custom scripts to do everything. I think I've added the 3rd org properly as if I try to get the config again I am able to see that the org config is there